# I want to change the src each time the user click the button, how do I do that?

Tags: javascript

I am building a simple app that the user is eating ice cream. Each time the user clicks the button, the image src will change into an image that has 1 less scoop than the other. But how do I change the src of the image multiple times?

```js
var iceCream = document.getElementById("img");
var imgSrc;

function eat() { 
var eating = document.getElementById("eat");
eating.play();

iceCream.src = imgSrc;
srcSelector()
}

function srcSelector() { 
if ( iceCream.src === "images/5scoops.jpg") { 
imgSrc = "4scoops.jpg";
}
}
```

```css
img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 }
 
 button { 
 position: absolute; 
 left: 740px;
 right: 400px;
 top: 70%;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Ice cream</title>

</head>

<body>
 <img src="images/5scoops.jpg" id="img" alt="5 scoops ice cream">
 <audio id="eat">
  <source src="eat.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
 <p>the button also plays an eating sound</p>
 <button onclick="eat()">Eat!</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

I am sure from the 4 scoops image src but it doesn't work(in my original page). 
What I want to make:

1. the original 5 scoops' image
2. after a click, 4 scoops image
3. 3,2,1 until 0 and alert that there is no more
   Please help using no jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you don't mind I used kittens instead of ice cream but you get the idea:

```js
var iceCream = document.getElementById("img");
var numberHint = document.getElementById("number");
var scoopsLeft = 5; // we start with 5 scoops left

function eat() {
  if (scoopsLeft > 0) {
    var eating = document.getElementById("eat");
    eating.play();
    scoopsLeft--; // reduce scoops left by one
    iceCream.src = 'https://placekitten.com/200/200?image=' + scoopsLeft;
    iceCream.alt = scoopsLeft + ' scoops ice cream left';
    numberHint.innerHTML = iceCream.alt;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200?image=5" id="img" alt="5 scoops ice cream left">
<audio id="eat">
  <source src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Cat%20Meow-SoundBible.com-1977450526.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<p>the button also plays an eating sound</p>
<button onclick="eat()">Eat!</button>
<div id="number">5 scoops ice cream left</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot but I have the images in a file, images/5scoops.jpg, images/4scoops.jpg, etc..
how do I do that?

Comment: @BilalKhalid in that case instead of `iceCream.src = 'https://placekitten.com/200/200?image=' + scoopsLeft;` you have `iceCream.src = 'images/' + scoopsLeft + 'scoops.jpg';`
You can place the variable wherever you need to.

Comment: @BilalKhalid Happy to hear that! Would you accept and upvote the answer then? Thanks ;)

Comment: I would definitely upvote it but I have no enough reputation :).. and, how do I accept it? (I am a beginner in StackOverflow sorry)

Comment: @BilalKhalid No worries, welcome to Stack Overflow!  There should be a grey checkmark next to my answer, if you click it, the answer gets highlighted as accepted. A short help is here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers